# "#Error" when using Lookup in Microsoft Reporting 3.0

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, lookup, microsoft-reporting

We are using Microsoft Reporting for generating a daily report. I want to add another column to one of the tables we have. Initially, I had set this up correctly and the report worked fine. However, due to technicalities I have to use a different table (with exact the same data) so I edited the query and once I do that I star getting "#Error" in the cell calues of my column.

The cell expression:

```
=Lookup(Fields!fldFlight.Value, Fields!OutboundFlightNumber.Value, Fields!OnTime.Value, "DataSet")
```

I use the following query to form DataSet:

```
SELECT
 turnarounds_staging.OutboundFlightNumber
,turnarounds_staging.VisitDatabaseID AS [turnarounds_staging VisitDatabaseID]
,turnarounds_staging.STDDate
,events_staging.VisitDatabaseID AS [events_staging VisitDatabaseID]
,events_staging.OnTime
,events_staging.Event
FROM
turnarounds_staging
LEFT OUTER JOIN events_staging
 ON turnarounds_staging.VisitDatabaseID = events_staging.VisitDatabaseID
WHERE
 events_staging.Event ='PDC'AND
 turnarounds_staging.STDDate= @Date
```

Where @Date is a parameter indicating yesterday.

If I change the query to the original table (identical). It works fine.
Any ideas why this happens when turnarounds_staging is identical to the original table?

Comment: You'll get an error if the `Fields!fldFlight.Value` from the first dataset does not have a matching value in the `Fields!OutboundFlightNumber.Value` column in the second dataset (`DataSet` in your example above).  Have you tried just dumping the data from each DataSet into empty tables to ensure that the values you want to match are present.

Comment: It has matching values, for multiple dates in fact. That's why I use the date filter. Manually I see there is a  match between Fields!fldFlight.Value and Fields!OutboundFlightNumber.Value, so that shouldn't be it.

Comment: Can you show sample output from your dataset1 and dataset2? to show that both has common data between *Fields!fldFlight.Value* and *Fields!OutboundFlightNumber.Value* I also has the same insight with Jonnus.

Comment: I inspected the data in both tables and it appears you both are right. Though the data at face value is the same, it appears there is a datatype mismatch that I solved by converting the string in one column to an integer.
Thank you!